# XSLT Mapping to read from string data and create corresponding xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt

Any advice on how to achieve this via XSLT mapping

Source XML:

```
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='http://company.com/PaymentMethod' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>Company Account,Merchant Account,Reserved
Data1,Data2,Data3
Data4,Data5,Data6
Data7,Data8,Data9
</data>
</pay:MT_Source>
```

Target XML:

```
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='http://company.com/PaymentMethod' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
   <data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>
   <record>
   <Company Account>Data1</Company Account>
   <Merchant Account>Data2</Merchant Account>
   <Reserved>Data3<Reserved>
   </record>
   <record>
   <Company Account>Data4</Company Account>
   <Merchant Account>Data5</Merchant Account>
   <Reserved>Data6<Reserved>
   </record>
   <record>
   <Company Account>Data7</Company Account>
   <Merchant Account>Data8</Merchant Account>
   <Reserved>Data9<Reserved>
   </record>
   </data>
</pay:MT_Source>
```

Please note that there is '`&#x0a;`' at the end of each row and not comma.

Comment: edit your question and output for clear requirement

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0, tell us also which specific processor.

Comment: stylesheet version="1.0"

Comment: Daniel, can the same result be achieved via version "1.0" for this scenario as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option.

Note: `Company Account` and `Merchant Account` are not valid element names. I removed the spaces to make them valid. You can also check to see if the value will be a valid name by testing if it is `castable as xs:QName`.

**XML Input**

```
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='http://company.com/PaymentMethod' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>Company Account,Merchant Account,Reserved
Data1,Data2,Data3
Data4,Data5,Data6
Data7,Data8,Data9
</data>
</pay:MT_Source>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data[tokenize(@contentType,';') = 'text/csv']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\r\n?|\n">
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
              <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(replace(.,'\s',''),',')"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\r\n?|\n">
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
            <record>
              <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </record>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay="http://company.com/PaymentMethod"
               xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <data contentLength="1796" contentType="text/csv;charset=UTF-8">
      <record>
         <CompanyAccount>Data1</CompanyAccount>
         <MerchantAccount>Data2</MerchantAccount>
         <Reserved>Data3</Reserved>
      </record>
      <record>
         <CompanyAccount>Data4</CompanyAccount>
         <MerchantAccount>Data5</MerchantAccount>
         <Reserved>Data6</Reserved>
      </record>
      <record>
         <CompanyAccount>Data7</CompanyAccount>
         <MerchantAccount>Data8</MerchantAccount>
         <Reserved>Data9</Reserved>
      </record>
   </data>
</pay:MT_Source>
```

Working example here: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyU

Also, if the csv might have quoted values with commas inside, you can change the `record` portion to:

```
<record>
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." 
    regex="&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;,?|([^,]+),?">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="normalize-space(concat(regex-group(1),regex-group(2)))"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</record>
```

Updated example: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyU/1

Comment: Thanks...But if source has header field with ()                        <pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='http://company.com/PaymentMethod' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>Company Account (CA),Merchant Account (MA),Reserved
Data1,Data2,Data3
Data4,Data5,Data6
Data7,Data8,Data9
</data>
</pay:MT_Source> How can we remove () brackets in Company Account (CA),Merchant Account (MA) as well?

Comment: @EXPLORER - Just update the regex in the replace: `replace(.,'[\s()]','')`

Comment: XSLT transformation throws an error with replace(.,'[\s()]','') . Once again I just want to be sure that I am spelling it out correctly:                                        Source
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='company.com/PaymentMethod'; xmlns:soapenv='schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>; 
<data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>Company Account (CA),Merchant Account (MA),Reserved Data1,Data2,Data3 Data4,Data5,Data6 Data7,Data8,Data9 </data> </pay:MT_Source>

Comment: Target
<pay:MT_Source xmlns:pay='http://company.com/PaymentMethod' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
   <data contentLength='1796' contentType='text/csv;charset=UTF-8'>
   <record>
   <CompanyAccountCA>Data1</CompanyAccountCA>
   <MerchantAccountMA>Data2</MerchantAccountMA>
   <Reserved>Data3<Reserved>
   </record>
   </data>
</pay:MT_Source>